# Implementing Copy to Clipboard functionality for image in Angular App

Tags: angular, clipboard

I am developing an angular 8 app where I am displaying an image using  control and set the src to base64url string. 
Now I want to give user the option to right-click and copy that image to clipboard.
I tried using  ngx-clipboard package but it only supports text .

Thanks
Kapil

Comment: Do u mean base64 string  or directly image ?

Comment: I am using <img> control and want to copy image so that I can copy paste the same to word or excel